# Object from nested hash depending on key value

Tags: ruby

I get a google api response and have a the following hash:

```
api_response = {"0"=>{"id"=>"xxx.id.google.com^xxx", "hasMicrophone"=>"true", "hasCamera"=>"true", "hasAppEnabled"=>"false", "isBroadcaster"=>"false", "isInBroadcast"=>"true", "displayIndex"=>"0", "person"=>{"id"=>"xxx", "displayName"=>"Foo Bar", "image"=>{"url"=>".../s96-c/photo.jpg"}, "fa"=>"false"}, "locale"=>"en", "fa"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"xxx.id.google.com^3772edb7c0", "hasMicrophone"=>"true", "hasCamera"=>"true", "hasAppEnabled"=>"false", "isBroadcaster"=>"false", "isInBroadcast"=>"true", "displayIndex"=>"1", "person"=>{"id"=>"xxx", "displayName"=>"Bar Foo", "image"=>{"url"=>".../s96-c/photo.jpg"}, "fa"=>"false"}, "locale"=>"en", "fa"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"xxx.id.google.com^98ebb1f610", "hasMicrophone"=>"true", "hasCamera"=>"true", "hasAppEnabled"=>"true", "isBroadcaster"=>"true", "isInBroadcast"=>"true", "displayIndex"=>"2", "person"=>{"id"=>"xxx", "displayName"=>"John Doe", "image"=>{"url"=>".../s96-c/photo.jpg"}, "fa"=>"false"}, "locale"=>"en", "fa"=>"false"}}
```

I need to get the value of `displayName` from the nested hash where `"isBroadcaster"=>"true"`. (In this case the `displayName` is `John Doe`). I just can't get my head around this problem and would appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there will be only 1 broadcaster.

```
api_response.each do |_, hash|
  break hash['person']['displayName'] if hash['isBroadcaster'] == 'true'
end
```

For multiple broadcasters, this:

```
api_response.each_with_object([]) do |(_, hash), array|
  array << hash['person']['displayName'] if hash['isBroadcaster'] == 'true'
end
```

Comment: Thx. This method returns a string and that is what I looked for. +1 for multiple broadcasters although in this scenario there can be only one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do

```
# get all broadcasters
api_response.map do |_, hash| 
  hash["person"]["displayName"] if hash["isBroadcaster"] == "true"
end.compact
# if you want the first broadcaster, then
broad_caster = api_response.find do |_, hash|
  hash["isBroadcaster"] == "true"
end
broad_caster && broad_caster.last["person"]["displayName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `select` and `map` from `Enumerable` to get the first match.

```
display_name = api_response.select { |k,v|
  v['isBroadcaster'] == 'true'
}.map { |k,v|
  v['person']['displayName']
}.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about the keys how about:

```
broadcaster = api_response.values.detect{|h| h['isBroadcaster'] == 'true'}
broadcaster ? broadcaster['person']['displayName'] : nil
```

Or this will work too:

```
api_response.values.detect(->{{'person'=>{}}}){|h| h['isBroadcaster'] == 'true'}['person']['displayName']
```

Then it will find the first `isBroadcaster` or return `nil` in the event there are none.